# How to use user-agent in webview-flutter Flutter?

Tags: webview, flutter, user-agent

I tried to use webview_flutter plugin in Flutter. But cannot find to set useragent in there. It's should be there right ? it's a basic function of webview. Is there any possibility way to achieve that ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: After research, I found this and successfully test. `const user_agent =
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36';
`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
webview_flutter: ^0.3.13
```

introduced user agent, so now it could be used easily, like

```
WebView(
  userAgent: "random",
  initialUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102162/how-to-use-user-agent-in-webview-flutter-flutter",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Flutter_webview_plugin [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

you can add the below variables(including userAgent) as seen in their documentation:

```
Future<Null> launch(String url, {
   Map<String, String> headers: null,
   bool withJavascript: true,
   bool clearCache: false,
   bool clearCookies: false,
   bool hidden: false,
   bool enableAppScheme: true,
   Rect rect: null,
   **String userAgent: null,**
   bool withZoom: false,
   bool withLocalStorage: true,
   bool withLocalUrl: true,
   bool scrollBar: true,
   bool supportMultipleWindows: false,
   bool appCacheEnabled: false,
   bool allowFileURLs: false,
});
```